# curl command not working on bigrock server…?

Tags: php, linux, curl, server

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$adm=$_POST["admno"];
$phn=$_POST["phn1"];
include("model.php");
$db = new database;
$r=$db->register($adm);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{

 if($row["phn_no1"]==$phn  || $row["phn_no2"]==$phn  ||       $row["phn_no3"]==$phn)
{
$formatted = "".substr($phn,6,10)." ";
$password = $formatted + $adm;
echo $password;
$db->setpassword($adm,$password);
$pre = 'PREFIX';
$suf = '%20ThankYou';
$sms = $pre.$password.$suf;
session_start();



 $ch = curl_init("http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx?     USERID=ID&PASSWORD=PASS&SENDERID=SID&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
 header("Location:password.php?msg=new"); 

}
else
{
header("Location:register.php?msg=invalid");

}
}
}
?>
```

this code is working perfect on my local host .. but when i put it on server ... it takes lots of time but the code in curl command is not working it only refers to next page ... i checked that curl is enabled .. if i use only sms api without curl command it sends sms immidiately.... but i want to run both header and also want to hide my sms api.... is there any alternate of this ???

Comment: have you tried `curl_error($ch)`  for  checking problem in curl .

Comment: no.. actually i dont know how to use it.

Comment: Try `if($result === false ){echo curl_error($ch);} `see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) exmple. use `curl_close($ch)` use end of  script .

Comment: it is not showing anything .. i put this line in my code ... can you show exact where i have to put it

Comment: it is showing operation completed without any error

Comment: than there is no error in curl you have to check again DOCs of your api . Please don't use `mysql`  because it's deprecated function prefer [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: now i m using mysqli .. only in this page . it is not showing anything .. it stops on controller page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136516/discussion-between-gaurav-and-yogesh-arya).